What does the term "components of operator" in JJ. Sakurai's book Modern Quantum Mechanics mean?

We now demonstrate that if we take the infinitesimal translation operator to be
$$
J(dx^{\prime})=1−i\mathbf{K}·dx^{\prime} , \tag{1.202}
$$
where the components of $\mathbf{K}$, $~ K_x$, $ K_y $, and $ K_z $, are Hermitian operators.


K is a three-vector with three components, that are the operators detailed.

Please read this and consider to accept an answer.

Simple versions of quantum mechanical operators acts along single coordinate. Take for example momentum operator , which usually is defined as :
$$ \tag 1 \hat p = -i\hbar\frac {\partial}{\partial x} $$
But say you want this momentum operator to extend operating in all three dimensions, hence you need to vectorize it, like :
$$ \tag 2 \mathbf {\hat p} = -i\hbar\left(\mathbf e_x \frac {\partial}{\partial x}+ \mathbf e_y \frac {\partial}{\partial y} + \mathbf e_z \frac {\partial}{\partial z} \right)$$
Or we can re-write (2) with the help of vector components in a column vector:
$$ \tag 3 \large  \mathbf {\hat p} = -i\hbar  \begin{bmatrix}
           \frac {\partial}{\partial x} \\
           \frac {\partial}{\partial y} \\
           \frac {\partial}{\partial z}
         \end{bmatrix} $$
Column vector operator in (3) is basically a gradient operator, hence we can simply state (3) as :
$$ \tag 4  \mathbf {\hat p} = -i\hbar  \nabla $$
Hope it's a bit more clear to you why components of vector operator is useful.

Thank you, now I get it

$\textbf{K}$ is a vector whose compnents are operators,
$$\textbf{K} = (K_x, K_y, K_z).$$
It is not a vector in the sense that it is an element of $\mathbb{R}^3$, it would be an element of the vector space $(\mathcal{H} \otimes \mathcal{H}^\perp)^3$, where $\mathcal{H}$ is the Hilbert space, and $\mathcal{H}^\perp$ is the dual Hilbert space.

Think of the operator as a "vector" as such it has components along different "axes."  $K_x$, $K_y$, and $K_z$ are those components along the $x$, $y$, and $z$ axes.
